# why the vector derivative of $\frac{d(x^Ta)}{dx} = \frac{d(a^Tx)}{dx} = a^T$, why it's $a^T$ not $a$

Tags: matrix-calculus

$\frac{d(x^Ta)}{dx} = \frac{d(a^Tx)}{dx} = a^T$

I was confused by this simple formula for a few weeks.

I thought $x^Ta$ is an scalar, and it's derivative respect to a column vector should be an vector, e.g. $a$ instead of $a^T$.

am I missing something?

Thank you !!

Comment: I think it has to do with the fact that the scalar product is defined as $\square \cdot \triangle = \square^\intercal \triangle$

Comment: If $ f:\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^m $, then $ f'(x)$ is an $ m \times n$ matrix.

Comment: @ja72 I notice one paradox: could you please explain how this happens? Thank you! $\mathbf{a^T} \frac{d\mathbf{x}}{d\mathbf{x}} = \mathbf{a^T}$
\\

$ \frac{d\mathbf{x^T}}{d\mathbf{x}} \mathbf{a} =  \mathbf{a} $

Comment: @littleO you mean the Jacobian Matrix? why it's a row vector when the gradient is a column vector? Thank you !

Comment: @Long replace all $\square^\intercal$ with $\square \cdot$ and see if it makes sense. The transpose is part of an inner product in vector space.

Comment: @Long If I've answered your question, make sure you remember to click the checkmark left of my answer (it'll turn green once you do).  If not, what should I expand on?

Comment: @Bye_World So Sorry!!!! This was my first question here, I did not realize that checkmark. Thank you!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the definition of the derivative of a function $y: \Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R$ wrt the column vector $\mathbf x$.  $$\frac{dy(\mathbf x)}{d\mathbf x} := \pmatrix{\frac{\partial y(\mathbf x)}{\partial x_1}, \dots, \frac{\partial y(\mathbf x)}{\partial x_n}}$$  Notice that this is a row vector (by definition).

$y(\mathbf x) = \mathbf a^T\mathbf x$ is a scalar function so the result of differentiating it wrt $\mathbf x$ must be some row vector.  Now I assume you can prove that $\frac{d\mathbf a^T\mathbf x}{d\mathbf x} = \mathbf a^T = \frac{d\mathbf x^T\mathbf a}{d\mathbf x}$ in this case?

Comment: Thank you so much!  I have one more question about this definition. what was the gradient of this y(x) w.r.t x? was it a column vector?

Comment: It has the same components.  But whether it's represented by a row or column vector is not entirely standardized.  Different authors choose one or the other.